# fullcalendar not showing events

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, fullcalendar

My setup is like this:

Based on this example http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar/examples/json.html I tried to get my own fullcalendar application working. I replaced 'events: "json-events.php",' with 'events: "http://localhost:8080/CalendarServletTest/HelloWorldServlet",' and changed the dataType of fullcalendar to 'jsonp'. (The Servlet is hosted on a Tomcat 6 server)

As a first try my servlet responses were just hardcoded to "[{"id":111,"title":"Event1","start":"2010-05-10","url":"http://yahoo.com/"},{"id":222,"title":"Event2","start":"2010-05-20","end":"2010-05-22","url":"http://yahoo.com/"}]" which is exactly the json feed used in the fullcalendar example linked above.
However, my fullcalendar application isn't showing any events and Bugzilla does not show any errors in it's console.

I'm really confused by this behavior... anybody got any ideas why fullcalendar works in the linked example, but not in my scenario?

Comment: Why are you changing the dataType to "jsonp"? Is the events servlet located on a different domain than your jQuery code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the reason for the change... I need to split the servlet and the jQuery code and thus need to perform crossdomain requests.

Btw. it's really me... somehow I got confused while trying to register my account with an openID. In the end I ended up with a new account.